# Get subdistribution hazard ratio and 95% confidence interval from stratified Fine-Gray models in R using crrs() from crrSC package

Tags: r, regression, survival-analysis

I am running stratified Fine-Gray models in R using the crrs() function from the crrSC package. When running Fine-Gray models with crr() function from cmprsk one gets the exp(coef) and confidence interval in the output using summary(). However I dont find this to be the case with crrs(). Anyone knows how to get the exp(coef) and confidence interval using crrs()?

Here is example code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
library(casebase)
library(cmprsk)
library(crrSC)

head(bmtcrr)

covariates <- model.matrix(~bmtcrr$Age)[,-1]

### Fine-Gray model:
fg_mod <- crr(ftime = bmtcrr$ftime, fstatus = bmtcrr$Status, covariates, failcode = 1, cencode = 0)
summary(fg_mod)

### Stratified Fine-Gray model:
fg_mod_strat <- crrs(ftime = bmtcrr$ftime, fstatus = bmtcrr$Status, covariates, strata = bmtcrr$Sex, failcode = 1, cencode = 0, ctype = 1)
summary(fg_mod_strat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no `summary.crrs` function. I checked to see if the names of the coefficients and variance-covariance matrices in `crr`-objects and `crrs`-objects were the same.

```
> names(fg_mod_strat)
[1] "coef"      "loglik"    "score"     "inf"       "vcov"      "h"         "uftime"    "tfs"       "converged"
> names(fg_mod)
 [1] "coef"        "loglik"      "score"       "inf"         "var"         "res"         "uftime"     
 [8] "bfitj"       "tfs"         "converged"   "call"        "n"           "n.missing"   "loglik.null"
[15] "invinf"
```

Those two names are.  If you use the function designed for `crr`-classed object you can get sensible output, albeit with an error related to the fact that counts of missing cases are not recorded in `crrs` objects:

```
 summary.crr(fg_mod_strat)
# Forcing a function labeled for crr-objects to handle a crrs-object
#---- results to console -----------------------
Competing Risks Regression

        coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z p-value
[1,] -0.0228     0.977   0.0112 -2.03   0.042

     exp(coef) exp(-coef)  2.5% 97.5%
[1,]     0.977       1.02 0.956 0.999

Num. cases =Error in if (x$n.missing > 0) cat(" (", x$n.missing, " cases omitted due to missing values)",  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Whether this is proper statistically might be something you can address with the package authors of `crrSC`. If it is a proper approach and can be sensibly interpreted in the same manner as with `crr` objects then you could suggest to the package authors that they provide a `summary.crrs` function in the package's next iteration. While they were at it, they could make the output consistent with other regression functions and change the names to `coef` and `vcov` which would allow the use of the `confint` function.